# Partial Match Binary Search of Complex Strings

Tags: python

Using python, I'm looking to iterate through a list which contains a few thousand entries. For each item in the list it needs to compare against items in other lists (which contain tens of thousands of entries), and do a partial comparison check. Once it finds a match above a set ratio, it will stop and move onto the next item.

***One challenge: I am unable to install any additional python packages to complete this and limited to a python 3.4.2 distribution.***

Below is some sample code which I am using. It works very well if the lists are small but once I apply it on very large lists, the runtime could take multiple hours to complete.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

ref_list = [] #(contains 4k sorted entries - long complex strings)
list1 = [] #(contains 60k sorted entries - long complex strings)
list2 = [] #(contains 30k sorted entries - long complex strings)
all_lists = [list1,list2]

min_ratio = 0.93
partMatch = ''

for ref in ref_list:
    for x in range(len(all_lists)):
        for str1 in all_lists[x]:
            check_ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, ref, str1).quick_ratio()
            if check_ratio > min_ratio:
                partMatch = str1 #do stuff with partMatch later
                break
```

I'm thinking a binary search on all_lists[x] would fix the issue. If my calculations are correct, a 60k list would only take 16 attempts to find the partial match.

However, the issue is with the type of strings. A typical string could be anywhere from 80 to 500 characters long e.g.

```
lorem/ipsum/dolor/sit/amet/consectetur/adipiscing/elit/sed/do/eiusmod/tempor/incididunt/ut/labore/et/dolore/magna/aliqua/Ut/enim/ad/minim/veniam/quis/nostrud/exercitation
```

and although the lists are sorted, I'm not sure how I can validate a midpoint. As an example, if I shorten the strings to make it easier to read and provide the following lists:

```
ref_list = ['past/pre/dest[5]']
list1 = ['abc/def/ghi','xry/dos/zanth']
list2 = ['a/bat/cat', 'ortho/coli', 'past/pre/dest[6]', 'past/tar/lot', 'rif/six/1', 'tenta[17]', 'ufra/cos/xx']
```

We can see that the partial match for the string in `ref_list` is `list2[2]`. However, with a binary search, how do I determine that the partial match is definitely within the first half of list2?

I'd really appreciate any help with this. Efficiency is the most important factor here considering that I need to work on lists with tens of thousands of entries.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about SequenceMatcher being unnecessary noise. The first line of the code provided is `from difflib import SequenceMatcher`. In my use case, SequenceMatcher is used to compare two strings and provide a ratio value of how well they match. 0 meaning no characters matched and 1 meaning the strings are identical. I have set the minimum ratio to 0.93 and the first string found which meets this requirement, is identified a partial match.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question on that part.

Comment: I would suggest spending more time creating a minimal reproducible example, with clear minimal input and output. It is difficult to properly optimize something that is not clear.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you cannot use a binary search though, as the inputs are not sorted according to the partial match function you are computing, e.g. `gbcd` will have a strong partial match with `abcd` and `zbcd` but any word starting with something different from `a` and `z` will be between the two.

Comment: How exactly do you determine a "partial match"? Does a prefix of the string have to match, up to a certain length, or could any match in the middle be a partial match, too? If, for instance, only the first K letters are relevant, or everything up to the `[`, if any, you could just strip the strings to those prefixes, put them all in a set, and then do a set lookup. Or maybe use a sort of prefix-tree.

Comment: partial match is simply score-based for the string. Meaning when two strings are compared, they have a ratio value for equivalence. If the minimum ratio value is met, the two strings are considered as a partial match. In this scenario, a prefix tree probably won't work but it's a good suggestion otherwise. 
For instance `'abc'` is a partial match for `'aBc'` but `'one/two/three/four'` may also be a partial match for `one/ten/three/four`, depending on the ratio value.

Answer (score 0):

So I did more research into the background of string comparisons and it turns out the initial problem isn't as difficult as I originally thought.

To get the midpoint for a binary search, I can simply use the `<` and `>` operators. Since every ASCII character has a value, it seems that python will check the strings on a character-by-character basis. In this case, it doesn't matter how complex the string is.

However, one caveat is that some strings in the lists may have a rare naming difference of an uppercase character. To combat this, I've added str().lower() when generating the high/low/midpoints.

Working code is below. I've lowered the min_ratio value here, to cater to the short test strings but I will increase it in my main program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Copyright 2009-2017 BHG http://bw.org/

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def binary_search_partmatch(arr, x):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    mid = 0
    min_ratio = 0.85
    partMatch = ''
 
    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) // 2
        # If midpoint is lower, ignore the left half of array
        if str(arr[mid]).lower() < str(x).lower():
            low = mid + 1
        # If midpoint is higher, ignore the right half of array
        elif str(arr[mid]).lower() > str(x).lower():
            high = mid - 1
        # x is present at the midpoint
        else:
            return -1
    # If we reach here, then the exact element was not present. Check for a close match.
    check_ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, x, str(arr[mid])).ratio()
    if check_ratio > min_ratio:
        partMatch = str(arr[mid])
        return partMatch
    else:
        return -2


def main():
    ref_list = ['past/pre/dest[5]', 'rif/six/1', 'testcase_no_match']
    list1 = ['abc/def/ghi','xry/dos/zanth']
    list2 = ['a/bat/cat', 'ortho/coli', 'past/Pre/dest[6]', 'past/tar/lot', 'rif/six/1', 'tenta[17]', 'ufra/cos/xx']
    all_lists = [list1,list2]

    for ref in ref_list:
        for x in range(len(all_lists)):
            result = binary_search_partmatch(all_lists[x], ref)
            if result == -1:
                print('Exact match found for "' + ref + '"' )
                break
            elif result == -2:
                if x == (len(all_lists)-1):
                    print('No match or partial match found for "' + ref + '"')
            else:                
                print('Partial match found for "' + ref + '": "' + str(result)+ '"')
                break


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Output:

```
>>> Partial match found for "past/pre/dest[5]": "past/Pre/dest[6]"
>>> Exact match found for "rif/six/1"
>>> No match or partial match found for "testcase_no_match"
```

I'd still welcome any recommendations or unforeseen bugs with my test scenario here. I'm not a programmer by trade, so I may be overlooking something important.